# Localizable.strings (base) x English

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

When you localize a file on Xcode 5 now, you have this "base" file, that I understand will be used if the user is using another language that was not localized. On older versions of Xcode, you did not have that.

I want english to be the base language, that will be used by default. So I guess that with this "base" kind, I did not need to have an "english" localization (if I want english to be de default), right? I simply put all english localization inside the "base".

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds good to me.

I have always had big troubles if I let Xcode generate new language files for me so I started to create them on my own with this little [script](https://gist.github.com/hashier/6480489).

- In Xcode just add the languages in the project settings (under Localizations) an make sure "Use Base Internationalization" is activated
- Run the script. This now creates all the needed translation files in you tree
- Just drag and drop them from you finder in your project (deselect the copy option)

The great think about the script is, if you have any updates in your code the script takes care of this and updates your translation files. Apple's own `genstrings` always overwrites everything.

Edit:
I wrote a [blog post](http://stackenblochen.blogsport.eu/2013/12/01/ios-localization-with-ilocalize/) about translating with iLocalize, might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

My trick is to export localization for English which is my base language. Then I use it as the base language and import it.

I use the following script to export all my languages localized strings and create the base localization file

```
#! /bin/bash

# Export all the localizations into 'xliff' files.

set -e # Abort on error
set -u # Abort on undeclared variable

LOCALIZATION_PATH="Translations"
PROJET_PATH="mobile-iOS.xcodeproj"

# Iterate over the list of supported languages (include your base language, in my case English).
for locale in de en-GB en es fr it ja pl pt ru tr zh-Hans zh-Hant
do
  echo "Exporting localizations for '$locale'" 
  xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath $LOCALIZATION_PATH -project $PROJET_PATH -exportLanguage $locale
done

echo "Create default Base localization based on English"
sed 's/target-language="en"/target-language="Base">/g' <$LOCALIZATION_PATH/en.xliff >$LOCALIZATION_PATH/Base.xliff 
rm $LOCALIZATION_PATH/en.xliff
```

Note that you can include "Base" in the list of languages but it won't include any value.

Comment: Can you re-import that "Base" xliff?  I didn't have any luck with that.