# Do I need English beside Base localization which would contain the exact same 'translation'?

Tags: xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'd expect the base file to contain my English words since my project has "Localization native development region" set to English.

Update - to clarify my question:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although I am not entirely sure if I get this correctly, I will try to answer your question TTBOMK.

Suppose you’re using `NSLocalizedString(key, comment)` from in your code. You can clearly see that the first argument is actually is a key for a string, rather than the translated (or to be translated) string itself. Therefore when you “write code” you actually don’t write strings in base language — or any other language for that matter. You should think it as if you're adding string placeholders in your code.

Later on, you’re supposed to create a `Localizable.strings` file for each language you would like to support, in the form of `key = value;`. To make your UI appear at least in one humanly–readable language you should at least have one `Localizable.strings` file with proper string values for each placeholder key.

For example: if you had `NSLocalizedString(@“ConfirmationButtonTitle", @“Yada yada”)` in your code, then it makes totally sense having a `Localizable.strings` file that contains `”ConfirmationButtonTitle” = “Tap here to confirm”;` element in it. If you don’t create a `Localizable.strings` file or no `Localizable.strings` file contain `ConfirmationButtonTitle` key, then button title falls back to `ConfirmationButtonTitle`, since it is the name of the placeholder key.

Having said that, most people prefer naming their keys exactly as string values for various reasons. This is arguably a convenient — and very common — practice, but could lead to conflicts in people’s minds.

So, if you were to create the previous `NSLocalizedString` example like `NSLocalizedString(@“Tap here to confirm", @“Yada yada”)` instead, then your default/base `Localizable.strings` file would probably contain an element like `“Tap here to confirm” = “Tap here to confirm”;`.

What happens here isn’t that you’re repeating yourself, but instead you’re naming your key exactly as your base language’s string value, that’s all.

**EDIT**

There always have been a base language concept, but as I understand it Xcode 5 emphasizes this even more: that’s good. If your base language is English, then you don’t have to have a `Localizable.strings` file for English, again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I understand the referencing and symbolisation of NSLocalizedString. Please have a look at my screenshot.

Comment: And I assume the base language would be English?

Comment: Exactly, so that's why I don't see the point in the additional English translations. Because the base translations alreadh contains English... I found this similar question with an interesting turn. Leave out English, because it will fall back to Base if it has other then French or Dutch in my case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677073/localizable-strings-base-x-english

Comment: There always have been a base language concept, but as I understand it Xcode 5 emphasizes this even more: that’s good. If your base language is English, then you don’t have to have a `Localizable.strings` file for English, again.

Comment: There’s a pretty good article here: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Comment: Hi @exalted, I have a question about xib files localization. Say I localize a view controller so I get a file called `ViewController.strings` containing the UI elements in the xib file. If I add a new UI element, the strings file doesn't update itself with the new element. How do I make it update?

Comment: @Isuru, ideally, you will want to ask a new question in SO. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Apart from addressing question what language end-users will see, you need to consider also what will be shown in the AppStore.
My current experience is that if you use Base for English, English won't appear in list of supported languages (how Apple knows in which language your base localization is) in the description of your app.

I've met this issue myself - base (English), German and Russian

Target settings refer to:

```
Localization native development region = en
```

But on Appstore it appears in this form:

```
Languages: German, Russian
```

no reference to English

I consider to duplicate base localization to English (not a high priority, as users see from screenshots that App works in English anyway)

**Edit:** there seem to be a different behavior in iOS8 - Application Settings (Settings.bundle) seem to ignore Base translation, if any of translations match your "Preferred Language Order".

In other words, App is localized: Base, German, Russian.
iPhone is configured to use English, preferred languages order is English, German, Russian.

Application settings come in ... German!

Once again: **this is applied to Settings only** not to the application itself!

Comment: Interesting point, but at least as of this moment, English is displayed first in the App Store in this case.

Comment: @SeaCoastofTibet I think that's because the "Localization native development region" is set to "en" in info.plist

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles.html) (scroll down to *Creating Strings Files for User-Facing Text in Your Code*), you shouldn't add `Localizable.strings` to the Base localization. Even if your development language is English, create a separate folder and `Localizable.strings` for English. Create others for each additional language you want to add.

## Further reading

- [Managing Strings Files Yourself](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles.html)
- [Localizing Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.htm)
- [Internationalizing the User Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html)
- [iOS Localization Tutorial](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881)
- [Working with Localization in iOS 8 and Xcode 6](https://www.appcoda.com/localization-tutorial-ios8/)
- [What’s new in localization in Xcode 9 and iOS 11](http://www.ibabbleon.com/copywriter-translator/2017/06/whats-new-in-localization-in-xcode-9-ios-11/)

Comment: You're right, the Base.lproj folder should only contains all the .storyboard or .xib files. When I need to create a new localization string file, for example: Common_Localization.strings, I should place it in a language folder, for example: en.lproj, then select other target localizations